# Group by not taken into account Yugabyte

Tags: yugabytedb

I am struggling for some time with performing a group by.
After seeing all examples, I am still not able to perform a correct group by for some reason.
My table is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS itvance.identityuserdata ( 
id TEXT, 
type TEXT, 
tenantId TEXT, 
version INT, 
data JSONB, 
PRIMARY KEY((id, type, tenantId), version)) 
WITH transactions ={'enabled': true }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select id, type, tenantid, version
from identityuserdata group by id, type, tenantid, version;
```

But, since you are not aggregating any thing, you not need to use **Group By**. You can just use **Distinct** clause

```
select distinct id, type, tenantid, version
from identityuserdata group by id, type, tenantid, version;
```